# Is there a HttpClient for android that doesn't retry on connection fail?

Tags: android, http

Actually i'm using Retrofit and OkHttp for sending a txt file to my server but i'm getting a lot of issues when like the file is sent but the device is gone out of range so it can't get the server response and i'm forcing the user to resend the file BUT it will cause an error on my server as that will be a duplicate.

The same thing happens if the network go out and return in some ms so my question is is there an HttpClient for android that doesn't work as REST so retries hidenly?

Comment: how big is your txt file? most of the devices can take care of that right now.

Comment: For OkHttp, see e.g. https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace

Comment: @phonemyatt it might be max 20/30 KB

Comment: @Michael yeah i've already read that article